# Use Facebook API to print Facebook friends

Tags: javascript, fbml

My end goal is for my site to be able to use Facebook API to print a user's (alphabetized) FB friends out on the screen (I have already done this much) and then have it so they can click on a printed name so that it then stores it on a list on MY website ('Favorite Facebook friends', for example).

In summary, I already made it so it prints out their friends alphabetically, **so from here I need my website to be able to store the names they click/choose from the list to be used at another time**.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function populateFriendList(session){
  FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name', offset : 0, limit :5000 }, function(response) {  
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++){
      var friend = response.data[i];
      FbFriends[i]=friend.name
    }

    document.getElementById('myFriendList').innerHTML = FbFriends.sort().join('<br>'); 
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('myFriendList'));
  });     
};
```

I will be forever grateful to anyone who helps me with this!

Comment: Where are you "storing"  this information ? or is this all supposed to exist in one run of your code ?

Comment: Are you intending to create server side or just stored locally in your browser? If you are using a server, which server technology are you using?

Comment: I intend to store it server-side. I am basically learning how to do this as I make progress, so I haven't decided nor am I yet knowledgeable enough yet to set that side of it up yet. I do not expect anyone to do this for me, I simply want to set up the basic code first and setup the database later (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created code that returns data. If you want to resend ( ie serve ) that data to another user then you need to store that data on the server side.

So you need two things :

1.) Server side code to receive the data that your existing JS code has generated

2.)A location for that data to exist. This could be files written by your server side code or a database.

So you might do something like this

1.) get your user list

2.) using Ajax send that list to server side code

3.) server side code stores that information in a data base

4.) when needed the server side code retrieves the list and formats for whatever your next use is

I think this site would be a good place for you to start learning about this [Tizag Ajax Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/index.php)

You can find examples for how to transform JS arrays or list to UI here [Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/List_Box.aspx) and here [Example 2](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss3p10.html)

you could then send the result of those selections to your server

Comment: Alright. The only bit I want saved that my JS code generated is the names that the user selects. Where do I go from here to make each name 'selectable' for sending to my database? ---Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! I will definitely begin with Ajax. However, what if I didn't want to send the entire list, and only a select few names that the user selects from the start? I am having trouble with making each name an element that the user can **select**.

Comment: Okay, thank you so freaking much for your help Stimpy. I will upvote you to hell once StackOverflow allows me.